# How to filter records based on a range in SSRS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Though this question has been asked, the scenario for all such questions were totally different and didn't answer my question hence asking a new question.

I have hard coded a SQL code in `SSRS query field`. One of the column is from a

```
 CASE STATEMENT

CASE WHEN (Amt_Requested > 0) 
THEN Amt_Requested ELSE Amt_Committed END AS Final_Amount
```

I want to add a filter for this column where I want records `BETWEEN` 25000 to 50000

I tried to create an expression on the Design page of SSRS

```
=iif(Fields!Final_Amount.Value >=25000 AND Fields!Final_Amount.Value <= 50000,Fields!Final_Amount.Value,0)
```

This satisfies the condition but doesn't filter the data.

I also tried adding a FilterExpression from tablix properties, but it gives an error stating

```
'Please check the data type returned by the FilterExpression
```

> PL note: The CASE STATEMENT is in SELECT STATEMENT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Tablix Filters definition, I would change the data type to Boolean, leave the Operator as =, and set the Value to True.

Then I would set the Expression to return a True/False result as you intially described.

This design is much more flexible as you can easily combine multiple fields, parameters etc in the one Expression.  It also avoids the fragility and obscurity of datatype conversions in SSRS.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to respond to my question. I found it difficult to understand your suggestion as I am just 2 months old in this field. In the Filter Expression of the Tablix properties, I have to select the column on which the data is filtered, the datatype automatically changes to float and that field is disabled. Also I want to specify a range to get only those particular records. So without specifying the range how can i get what I want. How converting the data type to Boolean will help in this case. I am sure what you are saying must be right just dont know how to do it

Comment: Hit the "Fx" button next to the column name and change the Expression to something like: `=Fields!Final_Amount.Value >=25000 AND Fields!Final_Amount.Value <= 50000`.  Then you will be able to change the datatype.

Comment: ok. I first changed the expression to '=Fields!Final_Amount.Value >=25000 AND Fields!Final_Amount.Value <= 50000'. Then went to Tablix properties, changed the datatype to boolean for Final_Amount and set the Expression to 'TRUE' to return all records with true value. When I run the report, it gives 'true/false values instead of the actual amount. More over the number of records also increase drastically, as the records are not filtered.

Comment: It sounds like you have gotten the wrong end of the stick.  I was referring to the Filter Expression, not the Expression in your Textbox.